# VoiceState always returning None as 'channel' value

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm messing around creating a discord bot, but the VoiceState objetcs that I get always have the channel value to None.

```
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, voice_states=True)
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
  print("Channel event", member, before.channel, after.channel)
  print(member.voice)
```

I'm not able to get the event channel values from after, before nor Member.voice.

Any suggetions? Is it bugged?

Thank you all!

Trying to get the channel from on_voice_state_update always returns None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the channels of a guild, you also need to enable the `guilds` intent, like this:

```py
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, voice_states=True, guilds=True)
```

Here is a list of all intents: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#discord.Intents

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! This wroked for me! I was confused as the only intent remarked as needed in the docs for the method was voice_states [link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=intents#voice)

Comment: I see where your confusion comes from. I think this is due to the listener technically working, but just returning None on the guilds, without the voice_state intent the listener will not work at all. At least that is my best guess